# How to filter javascript pagination when search

Tags: javascript, pagination

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2s6m.png)

I use jQuery simplePagination.js for pagination. The pagination is fine when not searching but when searching the pagination does not work. For example in the image above, I tried to search by month which is  "March". The data for month March only have 2 but it still show the other pagination. It supposed only have 1 page when searching for March. Please help me to find the solution for this problem.

This is my code:
`

```
<form class="form-horizontal style-form container">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 7%;">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Name</label>
        <input class="col-sm-6" type="text" id="name" style="margin-left: 5%;" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 7%;">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Month</label>
        <select class="col-sm-6" style="margin-left: 5%;" id="month">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option value="February">February</option>
            <option value="March">March</option>
            <option value="April">April</option>
            <option value="May">May</option>
            <option value="June">June</option>
            <option value="July">July</option>
            <option value="August">August</option>
            <option value="September">September</option>
            <option value="October">October</option>
            <option value="November">November</option>
            <option value="December">December</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 7%;">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Year</label>
        <select class="col-sm-6" style="margin-left: 5%;" id="year">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <input class="btn btn-sm" type="button" value="SEARCH" onclick="filtering();" />
    </div>
</form>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="data" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Year</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Alice Jay</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Park Jay</td>
                <td>December</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Janey</td>
                <td>March</td>
                <td>2022</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alex Lee</td>
                <td>April</td>
                <td>2021</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Karl Har</td>
                <td>March</td>
                <td>2021</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herry</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2020</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Wendy Lee</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rayan Otto</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ellie B</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>George</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tammy</td>
                <td>August</td>
                <td>2021</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John Johnny</td>
                <td>July</td>
                <td>2021</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kenny Daniel</td>
                <td>June</td>
                <td>2021</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Leon E</td>
                <td>December</td>
                <td>2022</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sam Henry</td>
                <td>February</td>
                <td>2022</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="pagination-container"></div>
</div>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var year = document.getElementById("year");
        var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
        for (var i = 2019; i <= currentYear; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
            option.innerHTML = i;
            option.value = i;
            year.appendChild(option);
        }
    };

    var names = document.getElementById("name");
    var months = document.getElementById("month");
    var years = document.getElementById("year");

    function filtering() {
        var Name = names.value.toUpperCase();
        var Month = months.value.toUpperCase();
        var Year = years.value.toUpperCase();

        var table = document.getElementById("data");
        var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            var td1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            var td2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
            var td3 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
            if (td1 || td2 || td3) {
                var txtName = td1 && (td1.textContent || td1.innerText);
                var txtMonth = td2 && (td2.textContent || td2.innerText);
                var txtYear = td3 && (td3.textContent || td3.innerText);

                if (txtName.toUpperCase().indexOf(Name) > -1 && txtMonth.toUpperCase().indexOf(Month) > -1 && txtYear.toUpperCase().indexOf(Year) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var item = $("tbody tr");
        var numItem = item.length;
        var pageParts = null;
        var perPage = 5;
        item.slice(perPage).hide();

        $('#pagination-container').pagination({
            items: numItem,
            itemsOnPage: perPage,
            prevText: "&laquo;",
            nextText: "&raquo;",
            onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
                var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
                item.hide().slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
            }
        });
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

the `numItem` variable was not being updated after filtering the data. that is why the pagination was still showing the same number of buttons even after the number of results has decreased

```js
    window.onload = function() {
        var year = document.getElementById("year");
        var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
        for (var i = 2019; i <= currentYear; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
            option.innerHTML = i;
            option.value = i;
            year.appendChild(option);
        }
    };

    var names = document.getElementById("name");
    var months = document.getElementById("month");
    var years = document.getElementById("year");

    // function to update numItem after filtering
    function updateNumItem() {
        var visibleRows = $("tbody tr:visible").length;
        numItem = visibleRows;
    }

    function filtering() {
        var Name = names.value.toUpperCase();
        var Month = months.value.toUpperCase();
        var Year = years.value.toUpperCase();

        var table = document.getElementById("data");
        var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            var td1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            var td2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
            var td3 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
            if (td1 || td2 || td3) {
                var txtName = td1 && (td1.textContent || td1.innerText);
                var txtMonth = td2 && (td2.textContent || td2.innerText);
                var txtYear = td3 && (td3.textContent || td3.innerText);

                if (txtName.toUpperCase().indexOf(Name) > -1 && txtMonth.toUpperCase().indexOf(Month) > -1 && txtYear.toUpperCase().indexOf(Year) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

        // call updateNumItem function
        updateNumItem();
    }

    var item = $("tbody tr");
    var numItem = item.length;
    var pageParts = null;
    var perPage = 5;
    item.slice(perPage).hide();

    // call updateNumItem function
    updateNumItem();

    $('#pagination-container').pagination({
        items: numItem,
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
        prevText: "&laquo;",
        nextText: "&raquo;",
        onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
            var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
            var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
            item.hide().slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplePagination.js/1.4/jquery.simplePagination.min.js" integrity="sha512-J4OD+6Nca5l8HwpKlxiZZ5iF79e9sgRGSf0GxLsL1W55HHdg48AEiKCXqvQCNtA1NOMOVrw15DXnVuPpBm2mPg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>



<form class="form-horizontal style-form container">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 7%;">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Name</label>
        <input class="col-sm-6" type="text" id="name" style="margin-left: 5%;" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 7%;">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Month</label>
        <select class="col-sm-6" style="margin-left: 5%;" id="month">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option value="February">February</option>
            <option value="March">March</option>
            <option value="April">April</option>
            <option value="May">May</option>
            <option value="June">June</option>
            <option value="July">July</option>
            <option value="August">August</option>
            <option value="September">September</option>
            <option value="October">October</option>
            <option value="November">November</option>
            <option value="December">December</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 7%;">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Year</label>
        <select class="col-sm-6" style="margin-left: 5%;" id="year">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <input class="btn btn-sm" type="button" value="SEARCH" onclick="filtering();" />
    </div>
</form>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="data" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Year</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Alice Jay</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Park Jay</td>
                <td>December</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Janey</td>
                <td>March</td>
                <td>2022</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alex Lee</td>
                <td>April</td>
                <td>2021</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Karl Har</td>
                <td>March</td>
                <td>2021</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herry</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2020</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Wendy Lee</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rayan Otto</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ellie B</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>George</td>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>2023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tammy</td>
                <td>August</td>
                <td>2021</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John Johnny</td>
                <td>July</td>
                <td>2021</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kenny Daniel</td>
                <td>June</td>
                <td>2021</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Leon E</td>
                <td>December</td>
                <td>2022</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sam Henry</td>
                <td>February</td>
                <td>2022</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="pagination-container"></div>
</div>
```

added the `updateNumItem` function before initializing the pagination, & also called the function after the filtering is performed